# Mootools click form button by classname

Tags: jquery, html, button, mootools, classname

Hey all i hardly ever use mootools for a website but i am in need of having a way to programmatically click on a button within a website using mootools.

The website loads the following mootools:

```
 mootools-core-1.4.5.js
 mootools-more-1.4.0.1.js
 mootools-more-form-1.4.0.1.js
```

The HTML for the button is this:

```
<div id="login-submit-action" class="unselectable form-action">
   <button type="submit" class="submit-2013"><span>Sign in</span></button>
</div>
```

I know how to accomplish this using **Jquery**:

```
$('.submit-2013').click();
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Option 1 / **[Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/WZKbu/)**

```
document.getElement('.submit-2013').click(); // not cross browser
```

Option 2 / [**Fiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ja6kG/)

```
var form = document.getElement('form');
form.fireEvent('submit'); // depends if there's a event.stop etc, may need to stub
// or simply form.submit()
```

Comment: That wouldn't work.. i need to set it to fire **programmatically** - not when i click it with my own mouse.

Comment: @StealthRT, aha, sorry. Read your question too fast. Edited my answer with new content.

Comment: @StealthRT, was this what you were looking for?

Comment: why `$$` and not `document.getElement`? if you have a form handler semantically it's better to fire the form's submit. if you have a click handler, in mootools it will be `.fireEvent('click')`. `.click()` is not cross-browser.

Comment: @DimitarChristoff, please answer the question. My Mootools knowledge compared with yours is like the difference between a Ant and a Mamut :)

Comment: @DimitarChristoff, "me" learning here. Is option 2 what you meant?

Comment: he has a mootools-more-form _handler_ (whatever that is, none of the code here actually shows what submits). 

since a form can be submitted via buttons or the keyboard, it's much safer to invoke the form's submit method rather than simulating a user action. anyway--semantically and for maintenance, this is better imo.

Comment: @Sergio yes, sorry it took so long to accept. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @StealthRT, nice it was helpful. Glad Dimitar also "fine-tuned" it.